# What is the difference between using comparable by passing instance of our model class to comparable and passing wrapper to comparable?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

Suppose I have a Student class with attributes name and id. And I want to sort the `List` of students in natural order of their respective ids using `Collections.sort()` method. I can do it in following two ways:

```
 public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

     private Long id;
     private String name;

     // getters and setters..

     public int compareTo(Student student){
         return this.getId().compareTo(student.getId());
     }
 }
```

And the other way is:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Long> {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // getters and setters..

    public int compareTo(Long id){
        return this.getId().compareTo(id);
    }
}
```

And then use the `Collections.sort()` method to sort the list of students. My question or confusion is what difference does it make if we use one over other as they both produce the same result.

Comment: When you say "they both produce the same result", did you use `Collections.sort()`? Please show us your test code.

Comment: @Jason I tested my code and found out that second approach doesn't work at compile time. It gives  The inferred type Student is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>. may be i got confused a little bit but it should be Student implements Comparable<Student>. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement `Comparable<Long>`, `Collections.sort()` will not be able to use it on a `List<Student>` because `Collections.sort()` will have no way of figuring out where to get the `Long` from to pass to `compareTo(Long)`.

Answer (score 2):

Comparable's type parameter dictates by what type of objects your type is comparable with. In the former example, you're making Students comparable with each other, and in the latter example, you're making students comparable with Longs.

Generally speaking, you should use `Student implements Comparable<Student>`. `Student implements Comparable<Long>` makes little sense from an OO design point of view, since I presume you want to compare `Student` instances amongst each other.

EDIT: As Jason points out in another answer, `Student implements Comparable<Long>` is also unusable with `Collections.sort()`, unless `Student` extended `Long` somehow. And that's not possible because `Long` is final.

Also, using `Student implements Comparable<Student>` allows you to encapsulate the exact comparison being done. If later on, you decide to change the internal representation of `id`, or decide that you want to use a different field, or implement secondary comparisons using multiple fields, and so on, then existing users of your `Student` type won't break even if you change the `compareTo(Student student)` implementation.

For the above reasons you will rarely see types "in the wild" where `SomeType implements Comparable<SomeOtherType>`. `SomeType` will most likely be comparable with other instances of `SomeType` (i.e. `SomeType implements Comparable<SomeType>`).